# Two spans, one is centered in div as if there are no another and another in the right side

Tags: html, css

I should implement something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="title">Header</span>
  <span class="label">today</span>
</div>
```

The Header should be centered in the div. And the label should be placed right after. So, I need something like this:

[image]

So, Header should be centered independently on a label span, as if there are no label at all.

Is that possible to solve it with pure CSS and if yes, then how? Markup can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:absolute` can do it

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center; /* center the text */
  /* to illustrate the center */
  background:linear-gradient(red 0 0) 50%/2px 100% no-repeat;
}
.label {
  position: absolute; /* out of the flow but don't define any position */
}

.title {
 margin-inline: 5px; /* control the gap */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="title">Header</span>
  <span class="label">today</span>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, didn't know it's possible using absolute without defining any position. Thanks a lot!